# append before a specific row id generated by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple rows generated into my page using PHP and MySQL, and I have a simple form that helps me to add more rows to database. What I want exactly is, that I have to add a row before a specific row with a specific id:

```
foreach($resInst as $installment){
$sum = $sum + $installment['payment'];
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $installment['infoid'] ?>"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td><?php echo $counter--; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $installment['date_now'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $installment['payment'] ?> $</td></tr>                     
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the `AJAX` script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_payment', function()
{
  var date_of_pay = $("#date_pay_now").val();
  var pay_now = $("#pay_now").val();
  //var id_pay = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  var id_pay = $("#select_to_pay").val();
  var pid2 = '<?php echo $patient_id ?>';
  console.log(pid2);
  if(date_of_pay == "" || pay_now == "" || id_pay)
  {
    $("#date_pay_now").css('border-color', 'red');
    $("#pay_now").css('border-color', 'red');
    $("#select_to_pay").css('border-color', 'red');
  }
  if(date_of_pay != "" && pay_now != "" && id_pay != 0)
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      url: 'add_payment.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {pid: pid2, date_o_pay: date_of_pay, pay_n: pay_now, id_of_proj: id_pay},
      dataType: 'text',

      success:function(result)
      {
        alert("Payment added!");

        //Append here
      },
      error:function(result)
      {
        alert("Payment didn't added! Please Try again");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I mean that when I add information into database that have the same `infoid` I need to append this new line before the `<tr>` that have had the same `$installment['infoid']`.

The problem for me is how to put a condition inside jQuery that said:

`if row of the id == id_pay ==> append before this line exactly`

Like this:

```
success:function(result)
      {
        alert("Payment added!");
        if($("tr").prop('id') == id_pay)
        {
          $(this).before("<tr><td>"+id_pay+"</td></tr>");
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('#'+id_pay).prev().after( put_your_inner_html_here )
```

Although, that might be interesting if your row was the first row ... but should still be ok since prev() would be the tbody

Comment: I will try it but first I added a script at the end of my question can you see it ?

Comment: I saw it, but I'm not really sure what you're asking now.  You know what the id of the selected row is, yeah?  id_pay.  Of course, in the success function it's now stored in data.id_of_proj .. (so $('#'+data.id_of_proj), but I don't get what you're trying to compare it to

Comment: or ... $('#'+id_pay).before( put_your_inner_html_here )

Comment: but getting error here `.after("<tr><th></th>""<th></th>""<td>"+cnt+"</td></tr>");` like `missing argument )`

Comment: You're putting headers inside a row

Comment: oh I get it. Thanks.